# How to find matched rows by skipping certain column(s)?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector `a`  such that

```
a<-c(0, NA, 1, NA)
```

and a data frame like this:

```
set.seed(123)
out1<-data.frame(y1=rbinom(10, 1, 0.3),
                y2=rbinom(10, 1, 0.4),
                y3=rbinom(10, 1, 0.5),
                y4=rbinom(10, 1, 0.6))
out1
   y1 y2 y3 y4
1   0  1  1  0
2   1  0  1  0
3   0  1  1  0
4   1  0  1  0
5   1  0  1  1
6   0  1  1  1
7   0  0  1  0
8   1  0  1  1
9   0  0  0  1
10  0  1  0  1
```

How could I easily find out the matched rows for `a` by skipping column2 and column4, such a desired results like that:

```
   y1 y2 y3 y4
1   0  1  1  0
3   0  1  1  0
6   0  1  1  1
7   0  0  1  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another way, using regular expressions:

```
a[is.na(a)] <- '.'
out1[grepl(paste(a, collapse='-'), apply(out1, 1, paste, collapse='-')), ]
#   y1 y2 y3 y4
# 1  0  1  1  0
# 3  0  1  1  0
# 6  0  1  1  1
# 7  0  0  1  0
```

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the prettiest, but It should work

```
idx<-apply(
    out1[, which(!is.na(a)), drop=F] == 
    matrix(na.omit(a), byrow=T, nrow=nrow(out1),  ncol=sum(!is.na(a))),
 1, all)

out1[idx,]

#   y1 y2 y3 y4
# 1  0  1  1  0
# 3  0  1  1  0
# 6  0  1  1  1
# 7  0  0  1  0
```

Where we basically extract a matrix from `out1` of only the columns we want to match, then we turn the non-NA values of `a` into an matrix of the same size. Then we do a matrix comparison, and use `apply` to find the rows where all values are TRUE (they all match). We can then use that logical vector to subset `out1`

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
> out1[apply(out1[, c("y1", "y2")], 1, function(x)  all(x==na.omit(a))), ]
   y1 y2 y3 y4
1   0  1  1  0
3   0  1  1  0
6   0  1  1  1
10  0  1  0  1
```

Comment: Thanks! But it seems the output is not exactly same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lapply` to find the relevant matches for each column, and then get the `intersect`ion of these matches with `Reduce`:

```
(m <- Reduce(intersect,lapply(seq_along(a), function(i) if(!is.na(a[i])) which(out1[i]==a[i]) else seq(nrow(out1)))))
[1] 1 3 6 7

out1[m,]
  y1 y2 y3 y4
1  0  1  1  0
3  0  1  1  0
6  0  1  1  1
7  0  0  1  0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
a = data.table(y1 = 0, y3 = 1)
out1<-data.table(y1=rbinom(10, 1, 0.3),
             y2=rbinom(10, 1, 0.4),
             y3=rbinom(10, 1, 0.5),
             y4=rbinom(10, 1, 0.6))


setkey(a, y1, y3)
setkey(out1, y1, y3)
x = out1[a]
setcolorder(x, c("y1","y2","y3","y4"))
```

Answer (score 0):

As one-liner:

```
out1[c(-2, -4),, drop=FALSE][apply(X=out1[c(-2, -4), !is.na(a)], MARGIN=1, FUN = function(x) all(x==a[!is.na(a)])), , drop=FALSE]
```